# How to load wp ajax for not logged users?

Tags: php, wordpress

I understand I should be using `wp_ajax_nopriv` as per the [doc says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action))
 but I am not sure how tho.

On the front end I do:

```
var ajaxscript = { ajax_url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>' };   
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxscript,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { action: 'data_fetch', dates: datesSearch },
  success: function(data) {
    ...
  }
});
```

I know I could define the `url` in `function` like:

```
  function myAjaxUrl() {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
             var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
           </script>';
  }
  add_action('wp_head', 'myAjaxUrl');
```

And that would make the ajax call on the front end like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl...
```

But how would I use the `wp_ajax_nopriv` in order to be able to access `wp-ajax` for not logged in users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is just register your function to a hook named as `wp_ajax_nopriv_{your_function_name}`

So, for your case, `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch' );` should do the trick.

---

**Registering an ajax function in WordPress:**

**1. Registering an ajax function in WordPress:** You can add this in the theme `functions.php` file.

```
// Simple Ajax function
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_simple_ajax_func', 'simple_ajax_func' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_simple_ajax_func', 'simple_ajax_func' );

function simple_ajax_func() {
  echo json_encode(array('success' => true));

  wp_die();
}
```

**2. Calling that ajax function from JavaScript:**

```
var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';

jQuery.ajax({
  url : ajax_url,
  type : 'post',
  data : {
    action : "simple_ajax_func",
  },
  success : function( response ) {
    console.log('Success');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure how to implement that tho as you use `/js/theme.js` which is not my case as I have my script within the footer.php directly on the page, could you update please?

Comment: You can do that like this - `var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';`

Comment: ok could you update the question to have the final code please? thanks

Comment: console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: site_data is not defined`

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Forgot to remove the `site_data` portion from the `site_data.ajax_url`. It should work now.

Comment: nope, stille not tehre,  it says `admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197459/discussion-between-gul-jamal-zim-and-rob-m).

Answer (score 0):

you misunderstand the wp_ajax action.

You must create a PHP function inside your theme using the wp_ajax filter.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_foobar', 'my_ajax_foobar_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_foobar', 'my_ajax_foobar_handler' );

// This is the function that you will fire when your ajax code hits the admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
function my_ajax_foobar_handler() {
   // Make your response and echo it.

   // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
   wp_die();
}
```

So, for the WP admin ajax understand that need to fire this function, you must pass it inside your ajax request.

```
//Note that the action here is what cames after the wp_ajax PHP function
var my_php_ajax_action_name = 'foobar'
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { action: my_php_ajax_action_name, dates: datesSearch },
  success: function(data) {
   // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: ok thank you, so how would I echo the ajax url within the function?